# Aspx and aspx.cs getting strings from different resx files

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization, resx

I created two resource files, "SOSResources.en.resx" and "SOSResources.pt.resx".

In my aspx page, when I try to use a string from these files as below, I get it from the standard English language resx file.

```
asp:Literal ID="btnDelete_Text" Text="<%$Resources:SOSResources, String1%>"
```

However, if I try to get the same string on code-behind as below, I get it from the Portuguese language file (which is the user language).

```
btnEdit_Text.Text = Resources.SOSResources.String1
```

The following code is used to handle this process. It is supposed to select the User's language, or English in case this info is not available. However, only the example from code-behind gets the user language. The example from aspx page always gets the strings from the English resx file.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        string lang;

        if (ActiveUser != null && ActiveUser.Language != null)
        {
            lang = ActiveUser.Language;
        }
        else
        {
            lang = "en";
        }

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
```

Can someone help me? How can I assure that in both cases the page will get the strings from the appropriate language? I'm not sure either if this is the correct way to perform globalization on .NET.

Comment: What is the value of `lang` variable which is passed to the `CultureInfo`?

Comment: It is the value of ActiveUser.Language: a language code such as "en", "pt" or "es" depending on the user. Or, in case this information does not exist in the database, "en" (the standard language for the system).

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of research I found this example that worked for me:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.85).aspx

In addition to that, there was another question which also helped me when trying to move the code to the Site:Master or to a PageBase.cs:

[ASP.NET Web Page Globalization & Localization in Master Page C# 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702296/asp-net-web-page-globalization-localization-in-master-page-c-sharp-3-0)